# How does copy constructor execute?

Tags: c++, constructor, default-copy-constructor

I'm trying to understand copy constructor in detail. While doing so, i made the following example,

```
#include<iostream>

class Test
{
private:
        int a;
public:
        /*
        Test(const Test &t)                          // User defined copy constructor
        {
            a = t.a;
        } */
        Test()
        {
                a = 120;
        }
        int display()
        {
                return a ;
        }
        void set(int var)
        {
                a = var;
        }
};

int main()
{
        Test t1;
        std::cout << "t1.a " << t1.display() << std::endl;
        Test t2 = t1;                                           //Default copy constructor is called
        std::cout << "T2.a " << t2.display() << std::endl;
        t2.set(99);                                             //Changing the value
        std::cout << "t1.a " << t1.display() << std::endl;
        std::cout << "T2.a " << t2.display() << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

I read online that default copy constructor does "shallow copy" So it means if obj1 = obj2, what ever change i do in obj1 or obj2 even after the assignment
needs to be reflected on both the object as they point to same location.
But in this example when i change the value in one object it is not getting reflected in the other. Same result is obtained when using user defined copy constructor.

Can some one clarify this topic, whether shallow copy is happening or not!

Thanks!

Comment: shallow copy for `int` is deep copy. Try having `int *a` instead of `int a`

Comment: The default copy constructor does a *bitwise* copy.

Comment: You've been misinformed.   A shallow copy does not mean that `obj1 = obj2` causes `obj1` and `obj2` to refer to the same location.   A shallow copy means that any members which are pointers are copied by value, rather than creating a separate copy of whatever the pointers point at.   The distinction between deep and shallow copy only matters if the object contains pointers - which your example does not.

Comment: @user207421 - a "default" copy constructor does a member-wise copy.   For basic types like `int` and for pointers that happens to be a bitwise copy.   For each member (or base) that has an accessible copy constructor, it uses that copy constructor.

Comment: View it from a technical perspective. For the computer, an object is a set of numbers. Like the row of some table, with no name tag attached, no idea when each cell ends and without any knowledge about what the data is supposed to be. Could be integer data, could be char values, you don't know without knowing the class. That data is copied on a default copy constructor. Interesting here are especially pointers: those are addresses to some memory. Their raw data is that address. Which you copy, which means that after such a copy, both objects have the same address stored in that pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A shallow copy is not something special that you need to remember as rule. Instead it is just something that happens as a consequence of using a reference or pointer. COnsider this example:

```
struct foo { 
     int* x;
};

int a = 4;
foo f{&a};
```

Here `x` points to `a` and if you copy `f` the new instances `x` will point to the same `a`. Thats a shallow copy. A deep copy would be to respect that not only `x`, but also what `x` points to, is an integral part of `foo` and needs to be copied as well. In general the compiler cannot decide what you want. Is `x` just a reference, or is what `x` refers to also part of `foo`? Hence what you get is the obvious: Only the members are copied not what they might refer to.

Now, if you copy the `foo` and then modify the value `x` points to, then this will modify the same `a`. A shallow copy was made. To my experience the terms deep and shallow copy are rather adding confusion than clarity. What you get for free is all members get copied (whether is is a shallow or deep copy). Only if you need more (copy also the pointee), you need to worry about shallow vs deep copies.

TL;DR: There is no deep/shallow copy in your example. For values this distinction does not make sense. Use a `int*` to see the effect.

Answer (score 2):

> I read online that default copy constructor does "shallow copy"

This is not the right way of thinking of the copy constructor. The default copy constructor is just copying whatever members are in the type as if applying the copy constructor in turn on the members.

**From reference:**

> If the implicitly-declared copy constructor is not deleted, it is
>   defined (that is, a function body is generated and compiled) by the
>   compiler if odr-used. For union types, the implicitly-defined copy
>   constructor copies the object representation (as by std::memmove). For
>   non-union class types (class and struct), **the constructor performs
>   full member-wise copy of the object's bases and non-static members**, in
>   their initialization order, using direct initialization.

So it is more like a deep-copy actually than a shallow-copy.

Answer (score 1):

Consider Shallow copy to mere assignment. So,

```
Test t2 = t1;
```

means

```
t2.a = t1.a
```

Since `a` is an `int`, If you modify `a`, from `t1`, it will not reflect in `t2`.
So for `int` shallow copy is indeed deep copy.

Consider the case `a` was of type `int*`. Now `t2.a` and `t1.a` both point to same memory locations. So if you modify the value at memory location `t1.a`, the same would be reflected via `t2.a` since they are infact pointing to same location.

Answer (score 0):

The implicitly-defined copy constructor of a class simply copies each member [[class.copy.ctor]/14](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.copy.ctor#14). Copying the members basically means that every member of the new object (the one being copied into) is initialized from the corresponding member of the object being copied in the same way as if you had written

```
T member(original.member);
```

where `T` is the type of the member and `original` is the object being copied. If `member` is of class type, this effectively boils down to invoking the copy constructor of `T`. However, your member is a plain `int`, which is not a class type. There is no copy constructor to call (`int` does not have a copy constructor); the `int` in the new object is simply initialized from the `int` of the original object, which boils down to copying the value of the original `int` into the new `int`…

Your compiler does not distinguish between deep copy versus shallow copy, it doesn't even know what "deep copy" or "shallow copy" would be supposed to mean. There is no such thing as a deep copy or a shallow copy in C++ at the language level. These are simply terms that are commonly used by programmers to talk about different approaches for copying objects that *logically* (but not physically) contain other objects…